# In 2016, what is the correct way to create a commercial MS Office Add In?

Tags: .net, excel, office-addins

I've been writing VB6 code for Outlook and Excel for at least 10 years, but it's generally written in the VB Editor and saved as the default project or a worksheet module, therefore not very portable.

I'm at the stage now where I want to switch to .net and write proper add-ins, that I can distribute and potentially sell (so would need to be protected and installable).

However, there seems to be a lot of conflicting advice out there about how to do this, and what software to use.

I'd really like to know the definitive way to do this in 2016;

- What software to use (I presume, either the paid or free version of VS)
- What language to use (I assume a flavour of .net)
- What I need to do to be able to distribute or sell the addin (do they still need to be signed?)
- any advice on definitive resources to make the switch from hacker-style projects to stand alone projects

Apologies if this sounds vague, or isn't the correct format for SO; I'm a web developer, mainly open source technologies, so the MS stack (Office aside) has always been a different world for me.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tools of choice for .NET are VSTO, XL DNA and Addin Express.
VSTO is OK if you don't need performance (the Interop layer gives a high overhead) and does not support UDFs. Its slightly problematic across XL versions.
XL DNA is free, fast (both XLL and COM-Interop), supports UDFs and is open source.
 Addin Express is not free, but also fast, supports UDFs and good cross-version support.
 All .NET  addins require obfuscation for IP protection and support both 64-bit and 32-bit Excel (which VB6 does not).

Comment: Thanks Charles; that's really useful info. I see my question has a couple of down votes already, and looking at the SO "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" I can maybe understand why, so I appreciate you taking the time to outline the options.